# CORS - Allow origin null with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have clients (Cordova apps on iOS with the WKWebView engine) which make ajax requests with a origin of null. As of CORS specification, origin null seems to be valid. So it should be possible to configure that on my ASP.NET Web API aswell. But my ASP.NET Web API rejects the requests with the following configuration:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Got the same problem

Comment: Have you enabled cors in the webconfig?

Comment: no, but just to clarify, CORS is working fine. Only requests with: **Request Headers Origin: null** do not work

Comment: CORS should be enabled at WEBAPI site, If not enabled.

Comment: Have you added [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] to your WebAPI controller methods?

Comment: Any updates/solutions?